# Change active link color for specific page(s)

Tags: css

In my CSS there is the following, where the active link is a function of the text color:

```
}
a:active {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.page a.active {
    opacity: .4;
}
```

I am trying override this so certain links (but not all) are solid black. I have tried creating a special class, like this:

```
.blackactivelink {
     color: #000;
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `.page a.blackactivelink:active { color: #000; opacity: 1; }`?

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be right method. Unfortunately the link only blinks black when I click it, it doesn't stay black. Any thoughts?

Comment: The issue was the colon. Should be: .page a.blackactivelink.active

Answer (score 0):

I hpe this example helps! Pretty much I just gave two different classes to the link tags and then styled them accordingly on the CSS. =}

```css
.linkActive{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:blue;
}

.linkActive:active{
  color:yellow;
}

.linkActiveBlack:active{
  color:black;
}
```

```html
<a href=# class="linkActive linkActiveBlack">Meow Meow</a>
<br>
<a href=# class="linkActive ">Meow Meow</a>
<br>
<a href=# class="linkActive linkActiveBlack">Meow Meow</a>
<br>
<a href=# class="linkActive ">Meow Meow</a>
<br>
<a href=# class="linkActive linkActiveBlack">Meow Meow</a>
<br>
<a href=# class="linkActive ">Meow Meow</a>
<br>
<a href=# class="linkActive linkActiveBlack">Meow Meow</a>
<br>
```